# Suppress emitting of default values in WCF ODATA

Tags: wcf-data-services

I have a data entity POCO set up in a self-hosted WCF ODATA service running WCF Data Services 5.5.

The data entity has several string properties that will often be null. I'd like to suppress output of these properties when they are null to reduce the size of the data that crosses the wire.

```
[DataServiceEntity]
[DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class MyData
{ 
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

`DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)` seems to have no effect on data entity serialization:

```
{
"Id":"test4",
"Description":null
}
```

How can I persuade WCF Data Services to suppress that null property?

Comment: Could you possibly descend from IgnoreDataMember (or its parent) to implement IgnoreIfNull that would look like IgnoreDataMember to the serialization runtime?

Comment: IgnoreDataMember doesn't actively participate in the determination of what will be serialized - it's just a static flag that the DataContractSerializer looks for. If we create an IgnoreIfNull that inherits from IgnoreDataMember, DataContractSerializer will just see it as being IgnoreDataMember. No change in behavior.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that WCF Data Services is not using DataContractSerializer. These POCO classes are not tagged with DataContract attribute. Adding DataContract attribute doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: If your server is setup to gzip JSON, which it probably should, then the null's will occupy very little bandwidth...  it may consume more CPU time and memory on the client device though after deserialization.

Comment: AFAIK, WCF Data Services uses reflection to serialize entities and doesn't use the DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the ASP.NET WEB API OData provider? 
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData

You can write your own serializer. (Inherit from ODataFeedSerializer)
The ODataEntry class has a key/value property called "Properties". You can try to clear out the empty properties there.

Comment: Our project does not use ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why it may seem so difficult is that it is not an implementation problem, but a specification problem. I've rather quickly went through the OData specs (core/protocol and JSON verbose/light) and saw no mention of property omission except at obvious places like when using `PATCH`.

**A proper scan of the documents may reveal more accurate information.**

If I'm right, then you don't *want* to omit these as it may confuse clients over which you don't have control. If you control all clients and you're sure you will keep that control, you may hack something up, but I would treat this hack as an incompatible OData extension (with all that entails).

The best course of action is to verify this and if relevant suggest an improvement for the next version of the protocol. The [OData mailing list](http://mailinglist.odata.org/) may help.